# JS error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Newbie here that needs some help!

I am trying to access the dataset.type that I have attached to my html element in js but i get this error everytime. It pulled the array perfectly but wont go past it. I know its probably an easy answer but I cant figure it out.

my JS:

```
const houseCard = document.querySelectorAll('.home-cards');
const tabNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.tab__link');
const houseTab = Array.from(tabNodeList);

console.log(tabNodeList);
console.log(houseTab.dataset.type);
```

the HTML i am trying to access:

```
<li><a data-type="house" class="tab__link active">Houses</a></li>
<li><a data-type="condo" class="tab__link">Condos</a></li>
<li><a data-type="duplex" class="tab__link">Duplexes</a></li>
```

Here is my error:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGFoq.png)

Now if I take off `dataset.type`, it pulls the array just fine and as you can see the dataset and type are both in the DOM.
[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZpUj.png)
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOvxW.png)

Comment: Well you expect an array to have dataset? dataset is on the node in the array, not the array.

Comment: Probably you code runs before the DOM is fully rendered.

Comment: @PM77-1 No......no... no.... no... no

Comment: @epascarello I did until you said that... but i run into the error even if i run the `dataset.type` on the nodelist pulled from the querySelectorAll.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return NodeList is not a single element.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access dataset on array of HTML elements, whereas the dataset is defined on each element and not array.
Instead do this:

```
const houseTab = Array.from(tabNodeList);

for (const element of houseTab) {
   console.log(element.dataset.type);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. I didnt realize that I had to specify each particular element. Thanks!